# The origin of $∂^2=0$ and $d^2=0$

Tags: terminology, algebraic-geometry, differential-equations, category-theory

I know that formula $∂^2=0$ and $d^2=0$ very important in the homology and cohomology theory. And I understand that this formula was generated from the process of finding a solution to the partial differential equation. So, I want to know the origin and motivation of the formula $∂^2=0$ and $d^2=0$.

(In this question, $∂$'s meaning is that the process of finding the boundary of a simplex. Like below picture. i.e. $∂^2=0$ means that boundaries have no boundary. )

[image]

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39597/timeline-of-cohomology-1935-to-1938

Comment: A remark since we don't have an answer yet: I always associated these formulas with integral theorems, like Gauss + Stokes, or Green's + path independence — that is, the formulas are generalizations. (Perhaps that's what you had in mind in your PDE remark.) That may have to do with the order I learned things. And the FTC for single-variable functions can be subsumed under the generalization. However, I don't have any historical evidence that this was the motivation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hello, I'm thanks to your comment! But I have some questions. What do you mean 'Gauss+Stokes' and 'FTC'? Could you explain more precisely about this comment?

Comment: *Gauss + Stokes, or Green's ... and the FTC* means *Gauss' Theorem plus Stokes' Theorem, or Green's Theorem ... and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*

Comment: Isn't this just formalizing the geometric observation that the boundary of the boundary of a set is empty?

Comment: For instance, to compute the flux of the curl of a vector field over a sphere: You could apply Gauss's theorem to get the integral of the divergence of the curl over the ball contained by the sphere; and div(curl F) = 0, an instance of $d^2=0$. Or you could apply Stokes's theorem to get the integral of the vector field over the boundary of the sphere; the boundary being empty, this yields zero for the integral, an instance of $\partial^2=0$. Briefly: $\int_{\text{ball}}\text{div}(\text{curl}\ {\bf F})=\int_{\partial(\text{ball})}\text{curl}\ {\bf F}=\int_{\partial^2(\text{ball})}{\bf F}=0$.