# Motivation and history of singular homology

Tags: topology, book-recommendation

Among the many cohomology theory's branches I asked about last time, I was curious about $d^2=0$ because I know that it is the formula that is the basis of all cohomology.  So this time, I would like to ask a more detailed question than the last one.  I want to know the background of singular homology, that is, the motivation and history of singular homology.  I would like to receive a recommendation for a text-oriented book with little formula or an answer on the motivation and background of this singular homology.

Comment: It would be useful to include a link to your previous question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/16196/history-of-cohomology-theory

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks for your comment. I'll refer to the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding singular homology proper, its main development occurred in the 1930s and 1940s with Lefschetz and Eilenberg figuring prominently. For this history, Dieudonné's "*A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology, 1900 - 1960*" is rather authoritative (see especially pages 68-70). See also [Ronnie Brown's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Brown_(mathematician)) math stack exchange answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055619/original-papers-on-singular-homology-cohomology) in which he comments briefly on singular homology and references Eilenberg's 1944 paper.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.  I read Ronnie Brown's answer you provided as a link.  But I have one question about this.  Of course, I posted a question in the link's answer, but it appears that Ronnie Brown has been inactive recently.

Comment: This is my question! It is said that $∂∂=0$ appeared in Poincaré's paper. I am curious about the motivation behind why Poincaré was able to derive $∂∂=0$ from the history of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Poincare's original papers, Analysis situs and 5 supplements to it, contain relatively few formulas, make a good reading, and explain his motivation. If you can read French. Another good source is

H. Seifert and W. Threlfall, A textbook of topology,
which exists in English translation.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Does the 'Analysis situs and 2 addenda to it' you mentioned in your answer above refer to the 'second supplement to analysis situs' in [this file](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/poincare2009.pdf)?

Comment: I meant all 5 supplements.

Comment: Okay, I will see all supplements. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user1274233: Thanks for the link to the English translation.